# google app engine favicon.ico does not update

Tags: google-app-engine, favicon

I'm developing GAE App.

I have a `favicon.ico` in my static folder, as recommended and explained everywhere.

Now I changed the picture in the favicon.ico. In the local host I can see the new favicon.ico, but when I try to open the webpage with the url (on the server) I see the old `favicon.ico`.

It even persist when I uploaded a newer version of the app to GAE.

Comment: favicon is add to cache at first load. Have you try to clean your cache ?

Comment: thanks Corum. how do I clean my GAE cache? (or if you meant in my local browser - I have tried, it doesn't help)

Comment: change browser and see what happens

Comment: It may be problem with browser cache. Try clearing the browser cache

Comment: Its not browser cache. I have the same problem, I even tried a second computer ... same result. This is been cached in the GAE itself.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try looking at the favicon directly, e.g., go to http://mysite.com/favicon.ico.  If it looks right there, then it is just a caching issue that will resolve itself soon.